# Is there anything that either confirms or denies the possibility of a druid techsmith?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid

> Techsmiths are devoted to the development of new inventions and the progression of achievement in the name of the Wonderbringer.

Followers of Gond believe in actions over words and results over intentions. They strive to hone their crafting abilities until they can create elegant and useful devices to suit any circumstances. So, a druid who also embraces technology & inventions (whilst still honouring & respecting nature) isn't the traditional "Druid."

Is there anything in the books that either confirms that druids can be techsmiths, or else explicitly states that they cannot?

Comment: Hi Obi1. Please don't link to piracy sites providing full copies of classes & etc found in books people are supposed to pay for. Instead rely on that answers will be coming from people with their own copies.

Comment: Hi @Obi1. Your question's been closed since, as it stands, it looks like an idea-generation question, which consensus agrees are not a good fit for the StackExchange format here. You could, instead, ask if it is *possible* for a druid to multiclass into Techsmith, or if FR lore has any examples of characters who combined the two fields of interest in the way you describe.

Answer (score 11):

### A druid/Techsmith is infeasible according to the Forgotten Realms' rules

The rules given about how patron deities work in the Forgotten Realms preclude a character being both a druid and a Techsmith.

Firstly, from the 3e *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, page 23 (emphasis mine):

> Like clerics, the druids of Faerûn receive their spells from a particular patron deity, *always a deity of nature or animals*.

A druid's patron deity *must* be a druid whose portfolio is nature or at least animal-based. *Faiths and Pantheons*, page 8, backs this up by providing the following rules about the ability of deities to grant spells:

> Most deities can grant spells from the cleric spell list, the ranger spell list,  and from three or more domains. Deities with levels in the druid class can grant spells from the druid spell list, and deities with paladin levels can grant spells from the paladin spell list.

So a deity that is not a druid in their own right normally cannot grant druidic spells to followers.

Gond's portfolio is given as "artifice, craft, construction, smithwork"; he is not a deity of nature or animals, so not an appropriate patron for a druid in FR. Further, he is described on page 25 of *F&P* as having the class breakdown Rogue 10/Wizard 12/Cleric 8/Bard 10 (plus, of course, the default 20HD of outsider), which means he doesn't have any druid levels and thus cannot grant druid spells.

Since a Techsmith's patron must be Gond, and Gond cannot be a druid's patron, a druid would have to change patron from their original deity in order to qualify for the Techsmith class, an act which would cause them to lose all of their druid class features according to page 233 of the *FRCS*:

> It is possible for a cleric, druid, paladin, or spellcasting ranger (or anyother divine spellcaster) to abandon his chosen deity and take up the faith of another deity. In doing so, the divine spellcaster loses all class features of the abandoned deity.

Such a character can resume progress in their divine spellcasting classes once they get in good with their new faith and receive an *atonement* (as per the spell), but it's arguable as to whether or not Gond would be able to offer the normal druid class features and he definitely can't offer druid-specific spells. (If I had a player who wanted to do this, I'd probably just let them rebuild as a cleric after they completed their transition to the new faith rather than shackle them with a bunch of useless druid levels.)

However - the Forgotten Realms is notable as being the only setting that has such strict rules about what deities various characters are allowed to worship, and also in mandating that divine spellcasters *must* be granted their power by a deity. In any other setting, these restrictions are largely absent, and if Gond is available in those settings (for example, in Planescape, because Planescape assumes all other settings are available within it) it should be possible for a druid to receive druidic powers from their communion with nature but also worship Gond and progress as a Techsmith.

Comment: It may be worth noting that Forgotten Realms is literally the only setting in D&D with this property; a druid of Gond is possible literally anywhere else that Gond operates. The question is about FR, so this is the answer, but the exceptional status of FR in this regard warrants mentioning. (As for other settings that have Gond, if nothing else, Planescape does, since the Realms are included within Planescape, at least from Planescape’s perspective. A druid in the Outlands could certainly worship Gond.)

Comment: @KRyan *FRCS* and elsewhere describe Toril's unique cosmology, the World Tree, that's different from that of the Great Wheel… which is, I think, the assumption for the Planescape setting. Gond, for instance, has a World Tree "realm" adjacent to the plane the Golden Hills wherein the gnome pantheon resides. So, while a PC in a default Planescape campaign could probably pick Gond, I'm not sure that PC would get any spells, especially given how much more punitive *AD&D 2e* is. Or am I misreading? (Note that I know anything's *possible* in a Planescape setting.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is why I said “from Planescape’s perspective.” The Planescape campaign setting includes within it in the Forgotten Realms, or at least a version thereof, and therefore includes Gond. The Forgotten Realms campaign setting, contrarily, can be played with the World Tree cosmology and separate from other campaign settings, as described in *FRCS*; that’s (3e) FR’s perspective. Also, it’s worth noting that the whole World Tree thing wasn’t consistently adhered to in 3e, and was abandoned by 5e, and officially was just an “alternate theory” for the cosmos which remained unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

As other answers have stated, the Forgotten Realms requires that druids worship a deity of nature, which Gond decidedly isn’t.

On the other hand, *Dragon Compendium* features the urban druid, which seems like it would be a strong fit for Gond worship. Unfortunately, the description of the urban druid does not discuss the Realms (and Realmspace is the only campaign setting that has this requirement for druids), nor does any Realms book discuss the urban druid, so the details there will be up to your DM.

Answer (score 2):

As of D&D 3.5e, druids in the Forgotten Realms must worship a deity chosen from a list of nature deities.

Techsmith requires worshipping Gond, who is not a nature deity.